# installing a language rom file for the same phone but a different build number

Tags: custom-roms, 5.1-lollipop, languages

so i just want to install another language rom for my phone since it doesn't originally have it
now i found several files for my phone but the one that is available for my phone with my build number is just for keyboard, which was already available officially
the others however support both the interface and the keyboard
what happens if i install the rom that is intended for, let's say J120HXXS0AQE1 on my phone which has the build id of J120HXXS0AQF1?
because the difference is just for one syllable
that's it
will it be that bad?
please respond shortly if it works
thanks yall
the phone model is samsung j1 2016 sm-j120h

Comment: If you are able to install a ROM depends on two things: 1. The ROM have to be signed using the same cryptographic key as your installed ROM and second it's version have to be higher than the one you have installed because Android does not allow a downgrade. If one or both requirements are fulfilled is unknown to you as I neither know your device nor the ROMs you have mentioned. Note that even if you are able to install a ROM doesn't have to mean that it will work in the end. If two ROMs just differ in the language it should work as long as the hardware is not region specific.

Comment: well, i did it, i installed a rom that was not made for my phone's build number
and it worked!
(the phone is a bit slower, [probably due to installing a rom just now) it functioned alright, language is now changable for the interface as well
thanks the guy who helped me even though your english is a bit bad

Answer (score 0):

i did it becuase robert said that it'll be fine as long im not trying to meddle with too sensitive stuff such as hardware and whatnot.
so it works
as longas the change ain't too drastic

Comment: You did what? Please mention the steps you took to solve your problem.